# Unknown App listed under general settings, but not visible in the App Library

Tags: ipad, safari, applications, install

I tried to install an app from Safari which didn’t get installed unfortunately, but now there’s an unknown app listed under background app refresh settings with the following name, “Web” but it’s nowhere to be found in the App Library, I have already tried resetting the iPad but no results.

How can I remove this unknown app without having to hard reset my iPad?

Running iPadOS 16.1

[image]

Comment: You can't install apps from anywhere other than the App Store. I'm guessing whatever you tried to do instead made a springboard shortcut to a web page. btw, the latest iPadOS is 15.6.1.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am running beta, yes technically one cannot but it was an ipa which did get installed to some extent but the app wasn’t opening due to some signature issue, now I deleted the app, but I am guessing something went wrong and it left behind that web app or something (I don’t have much idea, tho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web clips and apps that are side loaded can get in this state.

You will need to exclude them from backup (in case you want to restore from backup after the next step) and then erase all content and setting from the settings app to clean this remnant of an app.

Disabling all entitlements effectively prevents them from running so you’ve done that. The only other way would be to reinstall an app with the same identity and then remove it cleanly.